# Android : Load image and use repaint method

Tags: java, android, eclipse, user-interface

I am new with android programming.
I am trying to add an image to android application in Java (Eclipse) {NO XML!! Only java code}.

In Java I used to load images like this:

```
Image = new ImageIcon(imagePath).getImage();
```

and also I used the repaint method.

My question is how can I do the same thing in android ?
I want to load an Image with Java code and not XML.

I have found some tutorials but most of them are in XML and some are just not working.
Thanks in advanced.
Ron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the most two common types of images in android:

1- **Bitmap**
        you can load Bitmap from resources using

```
  Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

this way offen used when loading images from internet or external directories, or when painting images using canvas.

2- **Drawable**
  and you can load drawables from resources using:

```
Drawable drawabl = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

this way used when setting images for views, like `ImageView` and `View` background.

Comment: I can reach the ic_launcher icon but when I am trying to add my own Image to drawable-hdpi I can't access it with R.drawable. any other way to load images?

Comment: `ic_launcher` is the image name in the resources folder, and check you are importing the correct `R` class, like `com.myapp.R` **not** `android.R`

Comment: Thanks! I used BitmapFactory.decodeResources... and the repaint method replaced with onDraw